# Get class of type which is initialized with null

Tags: java, android, class, nullpointerexception, freemarker

my problem is that I create java code with Freemarker and I need the type of a variable, which is not initialized. I need the type, because there are specified methods for each class type.

So I have a custom class that implements from Parcelable.

```
int id;
  public MyClass(Parcel parcel) {   
    if(id.getClass().toString().equals("Long")) id=parcel.readLong();
    if(id.getClass().toString().equals("String")) id=parcel.readString();
  }
```

I know there is a method readValue() but that solved not my problem, because the same problem is, if I want to write the Objects.

So that is the main problem. I hope you understand this and you can help.

Thanks

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean here - `id` is of type `int`, so you can't call `getClass()` to start with. Please clarify.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get type of an object with an object of null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378132/get-type-of-an-object-with-an-object-of-null)

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you mean but I think you are looking for

> instanceof

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think it is not possibile to get class type, because in this case id referenced on null, and that is not a type.