# Get type of an object with an object of null?

Tags: java, runtime, runtime-error

The following code does compile, but why do I get a run time exception?

```
String b = null;
System.out.println(b.getClass());
```

Error I get is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How can I get the type of the object even if it's set to null?

**Edit**
I realize there is no object present, but there still is an object b of type String. Even if it holds no object, it still has a type. How do I get at the type of an object, regardless of if it holds an object or if it does not.

Comment: It doesn't have a type, it is `null`.

Answer (score 17):

When you have

```
String b = null;
```

what you actually have is a variable of reference type `String` that is referencing [`null`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1). You cannot dereference `null` to invoke a method.

With local variables you cannot do what you are asking.

With member variables, you can use reflection to find the declared type of the field.

```
Field field = YourClass.class.getDeclaredField("b");
Class<?> clazz = field.getType(); // Class object for java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 4):

Everyone else has appropriately answered that there is no type as there is no object but if I'm reading this correctly, I think what you are really asking is about how to check the type that your variable has been assigned.

For that I would refer to this link:
[How to check type of variable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993982/how-to-check-type-of-variable-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

There is no object here, and `null` has no type.
You can't do that.

Answer (score 3):

A *variable* is not the same as an *object*. A variable is a *reference* to an object.

You get a `NullPointerException` if you try to dereference a `null` reference (i.e., if you try to call a method or access a member variable through a `null` reference).

When a variable is `null`, it means it refers to no object. Ofcourse you can't get the type of "no object".

Answer (score 0):

Null references don't have a type. There's no object being pointed to, so you can't call `.getClass()` on the non-existent object.

If you're looking for the compile-time type, you can write `String.class` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To answer to your question you must understand what have you written.

`String b = null;` can be translated to. Reserve in memory space for a String class and fill it with null.

So there is not object in that statement. That is why you get NullPointerException.

To retrieve the type of such declaration you can use reflection mechanism but it only apply to class members.

Answer (score 0):

As the above answas state correcty, this is not possible. The closest I came up with is this:

```
<T extends Object> String typeAndValue(Class<T> type, T value) {
    return type.getClass.getSimpleName() + " is: " + String.valueOf(value);
}
```

You need to explicitly pass the type, but you cannot pass anything different than a suitable type (still may be supperclass) because it would not compile.